# Brown/ Orange spots on wall

Tags: walls, paint

I'm trying to find out what those brown/ orange spots are and how I can remove them. It looks like I have them in closets and less ventilated areas on my inside walls. I was planning on repainting the walls at some point but wanted to see if I needed to treat anything before painting on top of it.

Sample pictures.

[image: Spot in corner].
[image: Stains near architrave].
[image: Orange Spots].
[image: Stains on wall].

Comment: Likely rust from nails.

Comment: do you live in high humidity area? otherwise there is no reason for the screws to rust

Comment: I do, I live in South Florida. It's weird because it seems like it's happening in less ventilated areas (like closets I barely open).

Comment: The low air circulation in closets favors growth of mold (in general).  You can buy Damp-Rid which comes with a hanger, for use in closets.  Replace when the bag is full of water and there are no crystals left.

Comment: Bug poop could be a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Drywall original color (not painted) is yellowish brown.

So you have some areas that are not painted at all or badly painted.

That explains the Brownish -Yellow.

The dark spots are mostly too geometrical for mold, more like rusty screws.

However this area might be mold.

[image: mold]

Normally the drywall screws do not rust so easily, but they do rust if exposed to humidity. Does the drywall feels wet ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That's very helpful! The drywalls don't feel wet but I do live in a high humidity place (Florida). I'll get it checked out to see if it's mold.

Comment: @Armand since yo live in very high humidity place it is even more important to paint. The Mold likes dark and humid places (your closet)